# IO Error: Socket read timed out only when database is running JDBCTemplate query with IN statement

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate, hikaricp

Hello Everyone,

I am performance testing simple Rest endpoint with 60 transactions/second and out of 100k hits only 100 are failing with following error,we tried each and every way of increasing max lifetime and improving database memory, still getting socket read timeout error:

Query:

```
    >  select
    >         store,
    >                 product,quantity
    >                        from
    >                 store
    >             where store in (: stores) and product in (: products);
```

My connection settings are as follows:

```
    **application.properties** 
    
        datasources.spring.poolName= springDB
        datasources.spring.connectionTimeout= 100000
        datasources.spring.maximumPoolSize= 30
        datasources.spring.idleTimeout= 30000
        datasources.spring.maxLifetime= 600000
        datasources.spring.validationTimeout= 1000
        datasources.spring.leakDetectionThreshold= 90000
        datasources.spring.autoCommit= true
        datasources.spring.minimumIdle= 30
        datasources.spring.connectionTestQuery= SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
        datasources.spring.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

**Exception:**

- IO Error: Socket read timed out

```
           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:747)
           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:904)
           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1082)
           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1737)
           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1692)
           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:300)
           at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.isConnectionAlive(PoolBase.java:165)
           at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:185)
           at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:161)
           at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)
           at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158)
           at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116)
           at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:612)
           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669)
           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:694)
           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:748)
           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:216)
           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:223)
```

Comment: I don't know what is causing your socket timeouts. I do know none of the properties you are setting there have much to do with the Socket. They are all configuring the connection pool. Google around your Oracle driver to figure out how to tune _its_ sockettimeout, then figure out how to feed that into sprint's config. I don't think that will help, if I read the Oracle docs correctly, they default to 10 minutes: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/ESTUG/apbs02s23.html.

Log the actual query you are running and run it by hand. I'm betting its is slow and in contention with the other queries..

Comment: Your victims are getting backed up at the database. The database would have eventually got around to you...but your side you timed out at 10 minutes and didn't give it a chance.

A DBA hanging around while you are running this test can tell you if this is the case